# Why is my SendGrid account not wanting to send messages with Php?

Tags: php, sendgrid, email

I have a problem connecting SendGrid with PHP even though I typed the correct code from SendGrid website, but it does not want to send messages and my request does not appear in Requests list on my SendGrid account !
*API Key is correct*

````
        require('sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php');
    
        $api_key = "###########";
        $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
        
        $email->setFrom("support@codux.me", "Codux Inc.");
        $email->setSubject($subject_contacter);
        $email->addTo($email_contacter, $name_contacter);
        $email->addContent("text/plain", $message_contacter);
        
        $sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv($api_key));
        
        if($sendgrid->send($email)){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success">success send</div>';
        } else {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>We apologize! We are unable to receive your request</div>";
        }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved my problem**, check new code :

```
require('sendgrid-php/vendor/autoload.php');  

    $api_key = "########";
    $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();

    $email->setFrom("support@codux.me", "Codux Inc.");
    $email->setSubject($subject_contacter);
    $email->addTo($email_contacter, $name_contacter);
    $email->addContent("text/plain", $message_contacter);
    
    $sendgrid = new \SendGrid($api_key);
    
    if($sendgrid->send($email)){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success">success send</div>';
    } else {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>We apologize! We are unable to receive your request</div>";
    }
```